# python re: match everything but a double linebreak

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

There are a lot of questions like these on here, but I havn't found one that is quite what I need.

I need a regular expression that will match anything but a double linebreak. To be more specific, here is an example:

The data:

```
# 1 main header

__1.1__ company consents to transfer of the following end user license - including...

__1.1.1__ A subparagraph

__1.2__ company also consents to other stuff...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aquisquam veniam!
{: #lorem_section }
```

What I want to do is find every section that starts with `__[\d+\.?]+__` and ends with `\{: #\w+ \}`.

In order to do this, I need the middle of the regex to match anything except a double linebreak. I did this at first: `__([\d+\.?]+)__.*\{: (#\w+) \}`, but since it also catches double linebreaks, I get everything from `__1.1__` to `{: #lorem_section }`, where I actually wanted everything from `__1.2__` to `{: #lorem_section }`.

I read about negative lookahead, which is probably what I need, but I cannot seem to make it work properly. I tried the following 2 regexes, but neither yielded any result

```
__([\d+\.?]+)__.*(?!\n\n)\{: (#\w+) \}

__([\d+\.?]+)__(?!\n\n)*\{: (#\w+) \}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead.

```
r'(?s)__[\d.]+__(?:(?!\n\n).)*?\{: #\w+ \}'
```

[`(?s)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) enables  DOTALL mode, which makes the dot present present in the regex to match also the line breaks. `(?:(?!\n\n).)*?` will do a non-greedy match of any character but not of `\n\n` , zero or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eY0yR9/2)

```
>>> s = '''# 1 main header

__1.1__ company consents to transfer of the following end user license - including...

__1.1.1__ A subparagraph

__1.2__ company also consents to other stuff...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aquisquam veniam!
{: #lorem_section }'''
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?s)__[\d.]+__(?:(?!\n\n).)*?\{: #\w+ \}', s)
>>> for i in m:
        print(i)


__1.2__ company also consents to other stuff...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aquisquam veniam!
{: #lorem_section }
```

OR

You could do something like this also.

```
>>> for i in s.split('\n\n'):
        if re.match(r'(?s)__[\d.]+__.*\{: #\w+ \}$', i):
            print(i)


__1.2__ company also consents to other stuff...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aquisquam veniam!
{: #lorem_section }
```

Comment: that works. Although I still don't understand the syntax... The initial `(?s)` seems irelevant to the results... what does it do?

Comment: And also, what an unbelievable amazing website you linked to! Thanks for that. Nvm my question about `(?s)`. The link explained it

Answer (score 0):

Separate from the question of not capturing double line endings, note that the + and ? characters in your character group `[\d+\.?]` are treated as normal characters and not as quantifiers. That is,  they will match themselves so that your expression `__[\d+\.?]+__` will match such expressions as:

```
__?__
__+__
__?+???__
```

and so on, as shown in https://regex101.com/r/sQ8iN1/2

You want to use parentheses rather than brackets if you want the quantifiers to apply and you want repeating groups, as in https://regex101.com/r/sQ8iN1/3